# How to clear a browser cache in Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, browser-cache

In one of my scenario I need to clear a browser cache. I have tried with below one but it won't work.

```
 browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
 browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
 browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? Where are you attempting to execute these scripts?

Comment: this might be an overkill but I use `browser.restart()` [documentation here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.restart)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use it this way:

```
function LoginPage() {
  this.get = function() {
        browser.get('#/Login');
        browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
        browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
        browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
    }
}

module.exports = new LoginPage;
```

then I use this function in any of my test script which every time clears out cookies, session/local storage.

```
var loginPage = require('.././LoginPage'); 
loginPage.get();
```

Comment: Yep I tried with your way... If I converted it as function then its working fine. thanks for the help.

Comment: How about indexeddb?

Answer (score 3):

First of all I suggest doing it in forked browsers which will simplify your debugging efforts

```
 var fork = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
 fork.get('page1');
```

If you still insist on clearing everything you can restart browser

```
 browser.restart(); // Restart the browser clears everything (careful as it returns Promise)
 browser.restartSync(); // Same as previous but synchronous == await browser.restart()
```

Or even better restart fork

```
 fork = fork.restartSync();
 fork.get('page2'); // 'page2' gotten by restarted fork
```

Info: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L537

P.S. Not sure which parts you can't clear, but as a last resort I can suggest is incognito mode

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['incognito']
  }
},
```

Info: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options