# protractor - after browser.restart basePage.js ref is lost

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am automating angularjs application which is based on basic authentication.

after every test i need to delete cookies and restart my browser so that i can login with different user.

To do this i am using browser.restart() method of protractor

However whenever i perform browser.restart(), my basePage.js references are lost and eventually i get **'This driver instance does not have a valid session ID'**

my framework structure is as below

```
features
--feature1

pages
-page1.js
-page2.js
--basePage.js

step_definations
--step1.js

support
--world.js
--hooks.js
```

i am using

1. cucumber-js
2. javascript language
3. POM
4. protractor 5 version
5. nodejs

**After reading lots of posts, i got to know about reinitialize  basePage.js in world.js so that its references are recreated. But i am not able to understand how to do this?**

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218022/how-to-clear-a-browser-cache-in-protractor/45218725#45218725

Answer (score 0):

for session

```
browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();
```

If you found cookies is only issue
try this

```
browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```